# cocos2d runAction in loop

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

quite new to cocos2d so this is probably a school boy question.

I have ccMenu full of ccMenuItemImage's and want to animate each menu item in sequence to fade out.

I have an array with all the CCMenuItemImages:

```
menuItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2, button3, nil];
```

And i am trying to loop through the array and fade each button out:

```
CCFadeOut *fadeToAlpha = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5];

for (CCMenuItemImage *nextOne in menuItems)
    [nextOne runAction:fadeToAlpha];
```

This seems to work, but will only fade out the last CCMenuItemImage in the array. I know i could perform the action on the actual CCMenu, but i want to perform the animations one after another on each menu item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CCSequence for your work....

Instead of using loop use CCSequence like this..

```
[button1 runAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeToAlpha,use CCCallFuncN to call 2nd method, nil]];
```

In 2nd method

```
[button2 runAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeToAlpha,use CCCallFuncN to call 3nd method, nil]];
```

.

.

.

.

There is another way.... which is tricky... 
 Your fade time is 0.5.

```
float duration = 0;
for (CCMenuItemImage *nextOne in menuItems)
{
    [nextOne runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuraion:duration],fadeToAlpha,nil]];

  value = value + 0.5;

}
```

Check for syntax.. This way you can animate buttons one after another... Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
int index=0;
for (CCMenuItemImage *nextOne in menuItems){
   CCFadeOut *fadeToAlpha = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5]; 
   id fader = [CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:index*.5],
                                  fadeToAlpha,nil];
   [nextOne runAction:fader];
   index++;
}
```

also, avoid using same an action object instance with multiple runActions, create new action for each instance of use.